# Wait for VPN connection to be established loop

Tags: php, loops, exec

I was looking for a way in PHP to check and wait for vpn connection (tun0 interface) to come up before continuing with the code
here is what I come up with but it's not seeing any change after interface tun0 is up

```
$val = exec("/bin/netstat -i | grep tun0 | wc -l");
while($val == "0")
{
    echo "Still Not Connected\n";
    sleep(2);
}
echo "VPN Connected";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is just not in the loop :p

```
do
{
    $val = exec("/bin/netstat -i | grep tun0 | wc -l");

    if( $val == "0" ){ echo "Still Not Connected\n"; sleep(2); }

} while($val == "0")

echo "VPN Connected";
```

I'm using do-while structure because you will do at least one time the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that went completely over my head